# What is the domain for the function in this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, functions, notation

Suppose I have $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ and the function $g(x,y)$. Is this function of the form $g:\mathbb R^{2n} \rightarrow \mathbb R$? Because $\mathbb R^n\times \mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^{n+n}=\mathbb R^{2n}$?

But if I have $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ and the function $f(x+t(y-x))$. Isn't $f$ of the form $f:\mathbb R^{2n}\rightarrow \mathbb R$?

But according to [John's equation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John%27s_equation) the function $f$ is of the form $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$.

From Wikipedia:

Given a function $f : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ with compact support the X-ray transform is the integral over all lines in $\mathbb R^n$. We will parameterise the lines by pairs of points $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$, $x\neq y$ on each line and define $u$ as the ray transform where
$$
u(x,y)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+t(y-x)) \, dt
$$

Thanks!

Comment: Because $x+t(y-x) \in \mathbb R^n$ if $x,y \in \mathbb R^n$ and $t \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Everything depend on definition i.e. point of view - you can even count that $x+t(y-x) $ is from $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ if you want to change independently $x,y,t$. Or count it as defined on $\mathbb{R}$, if fixed $x,y$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ takes *any* vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. As @Azif00 pointed out, if we fix any $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, then for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$, the combination $x+t(y-x)$ is still a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, therefore, $f(x+t(y-x))$ is a valid evaluation of $f$.

On the other hand, $u\colon\mathbb{R}^{2n}\to\mathbb{R}$ is the function who takes two vectors $x$, $y$ as input, then outputs the integration of $f$ along the line defined by $x$ and $y$.

> **The way we actually compute this integral is via a 1-D integral**, as seen in the definition of $u$ above. This is because, integrating $f$ "along the line defined by x and y" is  the same as integrating $f(z)$ over all $z$ in the 1-dimensional subset  $\{x + t(y-x)\, |\, t\in\mathbb{R}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Reparameterizing by $t$ makes it a bit easier to write, while still having the inputs of $f$ well-defined, and makes the "one-dimensionalness" of the integral more explicit.

In other words, the function inside the integral is the mapping $t\mapsto f(x+t(y-x))$, so its domain is $\mathbb{R}$.